# call pandas plot function for path entry

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas dataframe that holds the file path to `.wav` data.  Can I use pandas `DataFrame.plot()` function to plot the data referenced?

Example:

typical usage:
`df.plot()`

what I'm trying to do:
`df.plot(df.path_to_data)`???

I suspect some combination of `apply` and `lambda` will do the trick, but I'm not very familiar with these tools.

Comment: If you want to plot data through `df.plot`, it needs to be in memory. Alternatively, see this link which offers an alternative with `pylab`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249430/4909087

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't possible. `plot` is first order function that operates on `pd.DataFrame` objects. Here, `df` would be the same thing. What you'd need to do is

1. Load your dataframe using `pd.read_*` (usually, [`pd.read_csv(file)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)) and assign to `df`
2. *Now* call [`df.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

So, in summary, you need -

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
... # some processing here (if needed)
df.plot()
```

As for the question of whether this can be done "without loading data in memory"... you can't plot data that isn't in memory. If you want to, you can [limit tha number of rows you read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008970/way-to-read-first-few-lines-for-pandas-dataframe), or you can load it efficiently, by [loading it in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas). You can also write code to [aggregate/summarise data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe), or [sample it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085547/random-sample-of-a-subset-of-a-dataframe-in-pandas).

Comment: this will load the data directly into the df, correct?  That might be awfully big...

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird Added some useful links to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need first create `DataFrame` obviously by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and then [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
pd.read_csv('path_to_data').plot()
```

---

But if need plot `DataFrame`s created from `path`s from column in `DataFrame`:

```
df.path_to_data.apply(lambda x: pd.read_csv(x).plot())
```

Or use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    pd.read_csv(x).plot()

df.path_to_data.apply(f)
```

Or use loop:

```
for x in df.path_to_data:
    pd.read_csv(x).plot()
```