# Python random sample from dataframe with given characteristics

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sample

I have a dataframe `df` with patients `subject_id`, including their `gender` and their `age`.

I would like to draw a random sample of size `n` from this dataframe, with the following characteristics:

- 50% male, 50% female
- Median age of 40 years

Any idea how I could accomplish that using python?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random Sample of a subset of a dataframe in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085547/random-sample-of-a-subset-of-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a little bit more complex than what [`DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) provides out of the box. A random sample satisfying each of your conditions could be generated (respectively) like this:

1. Filter for women only, and randomly sample `n/2`, then do the same for men, and then pool them
2. Filter for under 40s, randomly sample `n/2`, then do the same for over-40s and then combine them. (Though note that this does not guarantee a median of exactly 40.)

If you want to combine the two constraints, you might need to sample 4 times - women under 40, men under 40, etc. But this is the general idea.

Code for sampling would look like:

```
df.loc[df.age < 40, 'subject_id'].sample(n/2)
df.loc[df.gender == 'F', 'subject_id'].sample(n/2)
```